# Drag and Drop Image issue on New Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In the latest version of Fabric JS, image drop feature is not working as expected.

```
    function handleDrop(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // this / e.target is current target element.

        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation(); // stops the browser from redirecting.
        }

        var obj = document.querySelector('#draggable_items_container .drag_item.draggable_items');

        if($(obj).attr('data-type')=='image')
        {
            var image_url = $(obj).attr('data-value');
            var new_image = new fabric.Image(obj, {
                width: obj.width,
                height: obj.height,
                left: e.layerX,
                top: e.layerY,
            });
            canvas.add(new_image);
        }
        else
        {
            var text_value = $(obj).attr('data-value');
            if(text_value=='')
            {
                alert('You cant drag blank text');
                return false;
            }

            var params = {
                canvas_obj : canvas,
                text: text_value,
                left : e.layerX,
                top : e.layerY,
                font_size : 22,
                editable: false,
            };
            add_text_canvas(params);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Working Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ahammadalipk/w8kkc/185/

Not working in 2.0.0-beta.7

http://jsfiddle.net/dhavalsisodiya/w8kkc/412/

So how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What's not working exactly? I can drag the images into the box below in both fiddles you linked in Chrome v62.

Comment: sorry, js file was not updated in fiddle. Just updated it. Image is not shrinking.

Comment: Again, both still seem to work, but you have not explained what is broken. Can you explain what should be happening but isn't?

Comment: In old version, Image is getting fit (means you can see whole image) but in new version whole image is not loading. I will include Screenshot.

Comment: @David SS is added.

Comment: Couldn't figure out what's wrong. I would suggest trying the latest version [Version 2.0.0 rc 1](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/releases) and seeing if the issue is fixed in that. If it's not fixed there, [raise an issue](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues) on the Fabric GitHub page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
    width: img.naturalWidth,
    height: img.naturalHeight,
    scaleX: setImageWidth/img.naturalWidth,        
    scaleY: setImageHeight/img.naturalHeight,
    // Set the center of the new object based on the event coordinates relative
    // to the canvas container.
    left: e.layerX,
    top: e.layerY
});
```

You need to set actual width and height of image, then scale X and Y,according to your requirement. Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/w8kkc/414/)

Comment: Thank you very much, again.